# Unable to load the mojo 'test' - org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am building my apps with Maven-3 and i guess after auto-refresh of maven-surefire-plugin to 3.0.0-M1 i am not able to do build and getting the below error.

As a initial step, I have cleared the directory /org/apache/maven in my repository however still i am facing the issue.  Can anyone advise.  Note - if i am downgrading the surefire plugin to 2.x then I am able to build it.

Error log

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.444s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 08 16:04:53 GMT 2018
[INFO] Final Memory: 60M/704M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project TEST_PROJECT: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project TEST_PROJECT: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test)

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
  roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: There is no auto refresh that means imply that your builds are not correctly configured which means they do not define all plugins versions....

Comment: We started noticing this since November 7, 2018. I found out that they had just released a new maven binary (3.6.0) on 6th of November. I downloaded the latest and the latest works fine in Linux but has some other path related error (FileNotFoundException) on Windows. Can you try latest one?

Comment: @wildnux What kind of FileNotFoundExceptions? Please report the issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG

Comment: @khmarbaise that's what `-U` does. Unless you've chased that rabbit around a few planets, it's hard to know what's going to pull in what.

Comment: Tried with 3.6.0 Maven, still getting the issue [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project TEST-PROJECT: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors: [ERROR] [ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound

Comment: Related: [Maven not running junit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53433663/7795130); I ran into this issue because Junit 5 requires the Surefire plugin. This other question's answer addresses the 2.x version that can be included in the case of being stuck on a system where you are forced to use an outdated Maven (I'm on a machine whose administrator doesn't want to update from 3.0.5).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can upgrade your maven version to 3.6.0 latest to solve this issue.  This can be compatible from 3.3.9 maven version.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the comments on upgrading maven version, we updated our maven version and was able to overcome the surefire plugin issue using maven 3.3.9. Didn't get any issues.

Comment: Tried with 3.6.0 Maven, still getting the issue

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test (default-test) on project TEST-PROJECT: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound

Comment: Tried with wrong configuration.  After updating to 3.3.9/3.6.0 this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I found that my NetBeans was using a very old maven (3.0.5) even though I had a brand new maven installed.

On my Mac, I had to go to the menu "Netbeans/Preferences", select the "Maven" tab, and change from "Bundled", browsed to latest, and this got rid of the error above for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem until I discovered that we were not explicitly specifying the version of the surefire plugin. Once I changed our pom.xml file to set the version, it worked.

Comment: Can you let me know your maven and surefire plugin version?  I guess surefire-3.0.0-M1 can support only from maven-3.3.9.

Comment: mvn 3.0.3 - surefire 2.19.1 (yes, it's old.)

Comment: I'm using an old maven version, 3.0.5. I set the surefilre plugin version to 2.17. I found 2.21 works as well

Answer (score 2):

You can downgrade the version of maven-surefire-plugin to 2.12.4 using the pluginManagement tag. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing the issue in netbeans IDE you need to change default mavenhome version.follow the below steps
 in menu bar   tools->Options->click java tab --> under categories --> Execution --> Maven home drop down select manually installed  location of the maven

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SomMS's answer

But as an FYI, I found this thread, immediately dismissed that maven version could be the problem the as I just (last week) built this RHEL VM and it was new and shiny
... 15 minutes later I decided to check the maven version to find it was v3.0.5!
Hopefully the next guy doesn't make the same mistake

And if you are wondering how to get the version of whats installed try

```
mvn --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @SomMS's suggestion and upgraded Maven in order to fix the issue. It worked.

The problem is that, at the time of this writing, the latest version of Maven available on CentOS 7 is 3.0.5 (default repository), which is really old (Feburary 2013). Most other distros have way newer Maven versions available to them.

My only solution was to do a manual download and add path to its binary in `PATH` env-variable. Downside here is that now rpm/yum are not aware of its existence.